# Is there a way to host an app that uses MongoDB Atlas on Heroku without paying for an addon?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mongodb-atlas

I am in the process of teaching myself deployment to Heroku, and trying to host a simple MERN stack application to Heroku. So far, every tutorial I've worked on (at least four so far) has told me to use the addon mLab, which is 1) being depricated and 2) currently requires payment.

I've also now tried to use object Rocket which also requires a monthly payment. Is it possible to connect my Heroku app to MongoDB without payment? Perhaps without an add-on? I'm looking to turn around and teach others how to deploy their applications to Heroku, but if there is payment involved, that would be a real issue.

Edit: just to clarify, I am aware that MongoDB atlas is free, but what I'm not aware of, is  way to connect Atlas to my Heroku app in a way that is free.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Atlas free tier. No addons are needed.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to your MongoDB Atlas db is best achieved using Mongoose - a node module - at least that is what I am doing with my recently created React/Atlas application.  Mongoose is available for Angular as well and makes working with Atlas very easy. A google search will provide many tutorials, I'm sure.